# PHPStrom Xdebug and Wamp - Does not detect breaking point

Tags: php, wamp, xdebug

I can't get Xdebug work with PHPStorm2016 and Wamp. Here is some details.

I've installed PhpStorm, Xdebug on Chrome and WAMP on my local machine.
My working directory is located on WAMP in www/b2b-working/

PHP.INI

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

[Web Server pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGi6g.png)

[Debug Configuration and server pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RR4J.png)

If I'm starting to listen for PHP Debug Connections **the localhost is blocked and I need to click next in the debugger to display the page**

However, when I'm trying to actually have a break point on my project which is located in **localhost/b2b-working it does not catch any of the breaking point**. I don't know what I'm missing.

**The Validate Debugger Configuration on We Server is all checked**

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Basically, you need to edit the .htacess file with the [following instructions](https://gotterdemarung.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/enabling-xdebug-in-htaccess/)